# How to add a second column of values in the properties panel?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I created a property panel that displays the properties of the selected item. The property panel contains a category, property names and their values. I want to add a second column of values, but I do not know how to do this.
[Here](https://repl.it/repls/ZigzagMediocreWearables) is my extension code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the original `PropertyPanel.prototype.displayProperty` and create another `div` right next to the default one:

```
YourPropertyPanel.prototype.displayProperty = function (property, parent, options) {
    Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerPropertyPanel.prototype.displayProperty .call(this, property, parent, options); //if you'd like to keep the existing column

    var yourSecondColumn= document.createElement('div');
    ...//set up your column
    parent.appendChild(yourSecondColumn)
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one question: how can I write two properties, using this method. For example, I have got two objects using method("property dbId") for get properties dbId, but after initializing displayProperty I can't add two property, because my property object contain only one key for value. Please, check [this](https://repl.it/repls/CriminalOurAstronomy) code and advice me where is the problem?

Comment: You will need to figure out a way to retrieve the other property - establish a connection with the property so you can fetch the other. Alternatively override the `this.tree.myDelegate.createTreeNode` - originally it only calls `that.displayProperty(node, parent, options)` once so you can implement your own to create multiple elements for one node and access its parent to access other nodes for more properties